# Why is MemoryInUse[] Very Different from the Actual Amount of Memory Being Used?

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, system-performance

I call the `MemoryInUse[]` function, and it outputs about 256 Megabytes.

```
MemoryInUse[]

(*255979528*)
```

However, my activity monitor tells me Mathematica is using 5.45 GB and WolframKernel is using 2.32 GB.

Moreover, much more memory should be available than what `MemoryAvailable[]` tells me is available on my 16 GB computer, taking into account the other tasks on my activity monitor which use little memory by comparison.

```
MemoryAvailable[]

(*6579212288*)
```

***Why is this?***

Perhaps Useful Info

- I am not running anything in Mathematica.
- `$HistoryLength` was set to 0 beforehand.

---

### Update with Screenshots

The screenshots below are from different sessions than my original (which I do not have a screenshot of), but demonstrate the same issue.

[image: Example 1]

[image: Example 2]

[image: Example 3]

---

### 2nd Update with Screenshots

Here are some other sessions demonstrating the problem.

[image: Example 4]

[image: Example 5]

[image: Example 6]

---

### 3rd Update with Screenshots

Here is one where the difference between the `MemoryInUse[]` output and "WolframKernel" from the activity monitor differ significantly. `MemoryAvailable[]` seems off too.

[image: Example 7]

---

### 4th Update with Screenshots

The difference here between the `MemoryInUse[]` output and "WolframKernel" from the activity monitor is significant. `MemoryAvailable[]` is still off as well.

Mathematica 12.3.1.0

MacOS Big Sur Version 11.6

[image: Example 8]

Comment: What Version and OS are you seeing this for?

Comment: @user21 macOS Catalina, Version 10.15.3 and Mathematica 12.1.0.0

Comment: I can not confirm this for Linux. Does anyone else see this on Mac? You should report this to support@wolfram.com.

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting a new question. *Do* add this tag to someone else's question if it was verified to be a bug. Please see the tag description for more.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the activity monitor, and make sure that the table headings (different kinds of memory measurements) are visible? I cannot see this behaviour with M12.1 on macOS 10.14. Can you give specific steps to reproduce it? (I.e. what do you do to consume this much memory? I tried to create and free some large random matrices and cannot see such a large discrepancy.)

Comment: I'm pretty confident Mma uses internal allocation accounting of objects explicitly allocated by Mathematica allocator, which can be significantly smaller number than how the operating system accounts memory to be "used." (Explaining details might go deep into Operating Systems course end of things.) Also, you should look at memory usage of WolframKernel specifically. Amount of free memory seems to roughly correspond with physical memory - memory used + cached files on Activity Monitor, which is one sort-of-reasonable approximation of amount of memory that could be operated efficiently...

Comment: This question is not easy to answer. _One_ way this can happen is when Wolfram uses an external library that doesn't allow Mathematica to track its specific memory management. But this is only one way.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have included screenshots. I have some others as well. I am doing in-depth programming in Mathematica, so I will try to "filter out' the specific cause if I can.

Comment: MemoryInUse corresponds to the memory allocated in the kernel. It seems accurate in the screenshots.

Comment: Also, these seem to be sessions involving several hundred Out[] results, all of which are stored in memory by default. You may want to set [$HistoryLength](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$HistoryLength.html) to a smaller value.

Comment: @ilian `$HistoryLength` was set to 0 beforehand.

Comment: I missed that part of the post. Nevertheless, I do not really see a discrepancy between MemoryInUse and the amount shown in the Activity Monitor for WolframKernel.

Comment: @ilian I added more screenshots. In the last one, `MemoryInUse[]` and the memory shown in the Activity Monitor for WolframKernel differ by more than 1 GB.

Comment: You realize that `19434414392/1024.^2=18534.1`?

Comment: @user21 Yes, thank you. Good point. I still don't understand how `MemoryAvailable[]` and 'MemoryInUse[]' in Mathematica relate to "Memory Used", "WolframKernel", and "Mathematica" in the Activity Monitor. Nonetheless, I will try to recreate the initial (massive) disparity from my original session.

Comment: @ilian I added another screenshot showing a large discrepancy between `MemoryInUse[]` and what is claimed by "WolframKernel" in the activity monitor. I have more screenshots as well on my computer.

Comment: That is probably the result of using functionality (can't really tell what from the screenshot) that is loading dynamic libraries into the WolframKernel process. It is not unusual for such libraries to do their own memory management instead of using the kernel memory allocator, which means that any of their memory will not be reported in MemoryInUse.